# Which mobile development platform is easiest to develop?

Tags: iphone, android, ios, windows-phone-7

From your experience in developing mobile apps, which mobile development platform is easiest to develop? iOS, Android or WinPhone 7? And why would do you think it is the easiest? If you can order it from easiest to most difficult it is even better.

Comment: This can greatly depend on the programming background of the developer in question, especially if it's only one of C, C#, or Java.

Comment: I guess all of them via C# Xamarin.

Comment: @Den: keep in mind that even with Xamarin, the GUI development of the app is still platform-specific.

Comment: @rwong: how about "Build native UIs for iOS, Android and Windows Phone from a single, shared C# codebase" - https://xamarin.com/forms

Comment: @Den Xamarin Forms was released just a month ago, and when it is compared to each platform's GUI features, you will see the limitation of Forms.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

*From my experience* this depends heavily on the kind of application you want to do. Assuming that familiarity with the platform is not an issue.

**If you need to develop a "programming logic", "algorithms heavy" application**:

*WinPhone 7 -> Android -> iOS (ascending order of difficulty)*

**Reason**: WinPhone supports "out of the box" a richer set of languages strong in that area (e.g. C#, F# vs. Java or Objective-C) and has a pretty good standard library for "backend" stuff (roughly equal to Android, but far surpassing Cocoa, which is just embarrassing in this regard).

Objective-C is missing generics and its collection API is missing broad support for map/filter/fold etc. operations (the basic support is there thanks closures/blocks) and the underlying implementation of your datastructure changes with the number of elements it stores, which results in hard to predict performance when e.g. using NSArray, NSDictionaries etc. combine this with a pretty verbose syntax, outright insane method naming conventions and glaring holes in its API (e.g. no Regexes, no Parsers) and you end with huge amounts of boilerplate when implementing even simple algorithms.

Java is "just" hampered by a lack of closures (with the resulting code bloat transforming collections) and non reified generics (which are not a huge problem) and needing to check for Null Pointer Exceptions more often than you'd like. All of which result in non trivial amounts of boilerplate when trying to express anything where you want to transform one set of data into another set of data (which most algorithms are about in essence). F# (and to a lesser extend C#) don't come with this baggage, which in my experience results in a lot less code when doing "algorithm stuff".

If you don't mind the extra work you are able to use Clojure and/or Scala on Android which would put it in this regard in the same spot as WinPhone. MonoTouch/Mono Android allow the iPhone to come close in this regard, too.

**If you need to develop a "UI intensive", "interaction heavy" application my ranking is**:

*iOS -> WinPhone 7 -> Android (ascending order of difficulty)*

**Reason**: This is *IMHO* highly subjective, but Cocoa Touch gives you a very rich set of beautiful UI widgets and Objective-C - archaic as it is - is very good for handling "UI stuff" (Key-Value-Coding, Responder Chain etc.). WinPhone seems interesting in this regard (delegates/lambdas are very useful for handling asynchronous events), so I would say it is a close second. Writing GUIs with Android is IMHO unnecessary complex, some of this being a result of Java's lack of dynamism and/or closures.

**If you need to get really close to the metal - abusing the hardware to the best of you abilities, I would rank them as such**:

*Android -> iPhone -> ... -> WinPhone 7 (ascending order of difficulty)*

**Reason**: Android allows you to develop native apps and distribute them (in theory) without restrictions. On the iPhone there is no other option, but AFAIK Apple restricts you access to the OS a bit more than Android does. Apart from that I would say both are really close. WinPhone completely sandboxes you.

There are of course multiple other possible scenarios with corresponding rankings.

Comment: Nice. Thanks for the detailed explanation. Very much appreciated.

Comment: Can you elaborate more why Windows Phone 7 is more suitable for heavy logic type apps? Shouldn't Objective-C and Java be capable for that as well? Also another category that you missed is game development. Which platform would be easier?

Comment: Objective-C is missing generics and its collection API is missing broad support for map/filter/fold etc. operations (the basic support is there thanks closures/blocks) and the underlying implementation of your datastructure changes with the number of elements it stores, which results in hard to predict performance when e.g. using NSArray, NSDictionaries etc. combine this with a pretty verbose syntax, outright insane method naming conventions and glaring holes in its API (e.g. no Regexes, no Parsers) and you end with huge amounts of boilerplate when implementing even simple algorithms.

Comment: Java is "just" hampered by a lack of closures (with the resulting code bloat transforming collections) and non reified generics (which are not a huge problem) and needing to check for Null Pointer Exceptions more often than you'd like. All of which result in non trivial amounts of boilerplate when trying to express anything where you want to transform one set of data into another set of data (which most algorithms are about in essence). F# (and to a lesser extend C#) don't come with this baggage, which in my experience results in a lot less code when doing "algorithm stuff".

Comment: I have no experience at all with Game Development, so I can't comment upon that.

Comment: Alexander, thank you very much for the detailed explanation. What kind of apps that need heavy logic on the phone side? [Example would be appreciated]. Wouldn't you want to process the logic on the server side instead?

Comment: @jpartogi Programmers.SE isn't a discussion forum: comments are for getting answers clarified, not for asking new questions.

Comment: It is viable to use `C++` for the algorithmic part in iOS development, given the existence of `Objective C++`?

Comment: @C.R. it is perfectly viable and quite common (especially if you can reuse an existing stable C++ code base if your porting the project to iOS from another platform). If the C++ code is in constant flux and if you want to go all out with templates you should make sure that compile times won't be a problem.

But please note that my answer is 3+ years old and things have changed in the meantime! (e.g. depending upon how Swift works out and what Google does with Java – iOS will probably be soon on par with Windows Phone in programming logic and algorithms heavy stuff)